# How do I make a video on full screen in flutter windows?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I make  videos on full screen in flutter windows??

Double tap on the video and it will fill the screen in flutter windows??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PsS5.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, wrap your video widget with `GestureDetector` to detect the double tap like this:

```
GestureDetector(
  onDoubleTap: () {
    toggleFullScreen();
  },
  child: YourVideoPlayerWidget(),
)
```

Then you will create the fuction to control the full screen mode like this:

```
bool isFullScreen = false;

void toggleFullScreen() {
  setState(() {
    isFullScreen = !isFullScreen;
  });
}
```

The VideoPlayerWidget should be like this:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    .....

    if (isFullScreen)
      Positioned.fill(
        child: YourFullScreenVideoPlayer(),
      )
    else
      YourNormalVideoPlayer(),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work